# What happens to file descriptors in Python 3 when .close() fails?

Tags: python, io, python-3.x, resource-leak

The following Python 3 code exhibits some strange behavior (to me, at least) when I run it through `strace`:

```
import os
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print('Usage: ecpy <filename>')
sys.exit(1)
try:
    print('my PID: %d' % os.getpid())
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'w') as fp:
        try:
            fp.write('Hello Stack Overflow!')
        except IOError as e:
            print('### before close')
            print(str(e))
            sys.stdout.flush()
except IOError as e:
    print('### after close')
    print(str(e))
    sys.stdout.flush()

print('### after exception block')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Since I/O is buffered, if you run this code with `/dev/full`, it doesn't fail until `fp` closes at the end of the `with` block. That's no surprise. In Python 2.7.3rc2 (on my system), the code runs the exception handler after actually closing the file descriptor corresponding to `fp`:

```
write(3, "Hello Stack Overflow!", 21)   = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device)
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f9de3f78000, 4096)            = 0
write(1, "### after close\n", 16)       = 16
write(1, "[Errno 28] No space left on devi"..., 35) = 35
write(1, "### after exception block\n", 26) = 26
```

However, in Python 3.2.3 (on my system), the file descriptor is still open after the exception block runs:

```
write(3, "Hello Stack Overflow!", 21)   = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device)
write(1, "### after close\n", 16)       = 16
write(1, "[Errno 28] No space left on devi"..., 35) = 35
write(1, "### after exception block\n", 26) = 26
...
write(3, "Hello Stack Overflow!", 21)   = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device)
write(3, "Hello Stack Overflow!", 21)   = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device)
close(3)                                = 0
```

The interpreter tries to write to the file a few more times and fails silently. When does Python actually call `close()`? What is invoking it? This behavior seems to leak a file descriptor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the liberty of submitting an issue to bugs.python.org, let's wait and see if it pans out.

http://bugs.python.org/issue16597

EDIT: Looks like it's a bug, good catch!